# I`m trying to implemet 4 buffers in Verilog and I have some warrnings

Tags: buffer, verilog

```
`timescale 1us/1ns

module buffer(

    input a[7:0],
    input b[7:0],
    input c[7:0],
    input d[7:0],
    input en[1:0]
);
wire out[7:0];
// assign out = (en == 0) ? a : 1bz; //BUFF0
// assign out = (en == 1) ? b : 1bz; //BUFF1 
// assign out = (en == 2) ? c : 1bz; //BUFF2
// assign out = (en == 3) ? d : 1bz; //BUFF3
```

Can someone help me? i am getting warnings/errors. I`m trying to implemet 4 buffers in Verilog and I have some warrnings

Comment: 1/ Improve your formatting. 2/ *What* warning do you get? 3/ Is that the complete code because the module body is empty. 4/ Where is `endmodule`?

Comment: What is your question about this code? "Can someone help me" is not a valid question

Comment: @ana maria , i have modified the code format and added some more part of ur question,u can add some more details of the warnings/errors u are seeing

Comment: I guess your warning is around `1bz` which should be `1'bz` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Coded based on your intention of muxed output buffer.

```
`timescale 1us/1ns
module buffer(
   output [7:0]  out
  ,input  [7:0]  a,b,c,d
  ,input  [1:0]  en
);

 assign out = (en == 2'h0) ? a :       // BUFFER-0
              (en == 2'h1) ? b :       // BUFFER-1
              (en == 2'h2) ? c :       // BUFFER-2
              (en == 2'h3) ? d : 8'bz; // BUFFER-3

endmodule
```

Comment: there is no such number as `1bz`, it should've been `1'bz`

Comment: yeah its a typo

Answer (score 2):

Here is a corrected version of your code, that will compile.

```
`timescale 1us/1ns

 module buffer(
      input wire  [7:0] a,
      input wire  [7:0] b,
      input wire  [7:0] c,
      input wire  [7:0] d,
      input wire  [1:0] en,
      output wire [7:0] out
 );


 assign out = (en == 0) ? a : //BUFF0
              (en == 1) ? b : //BUFF1
              (en == 2) ? c : //BUFF2
                          d;  //BUFF3 (en == 3) 
endmodule
```

Comment: it can behave differently from OP's intention if 'en' is wider than 2 bits or not all possible values of 'en' are listed.

Comment: That is true that `d` would be the default value if `en` was wider. In that case, since no default behavior was specified. Would you suggest to add the following ?
`(en == 3) ? d : 8'bz; // BUFF3`
However in the current case 'en' was not parametrized and clearly defined as 2 bits wide, so all possible values are listed.